# Element z-index css property

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, z-index

I have 3 elements, two on the same level, and one child, all having fixed position. I need to  set the z-index properties to place the parent on the bottom, the element on the same level in the middle, and the child on top.

I've tried setting a higher z-index for the child, but it's not working.

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Here is the case http://jsfiddle.net/udENm/21/ (I need `red` on the bottom, `green` in the middle and `blue` on top, still maintaining `red` and `green`on the same level).

My CSS is like this

```
.red {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

.green {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

.blue {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: When you say you need red and green on the same level, do you mean it's necessary that they both have the same z-index, or just that they need to appear on the same level visually?

Comment: @SimonCarlson No, they do not need to have the same z-index, but need to have a z-index, as they might be contained in another element, with a possible z-index property set.

Comment: Your problem here is though that the child element will sort of inherit the z-index of its parent, even though the child has another z-index set. The childs z-index is only relevant to other child elements within the same parent, while the same z-index will have no impact on elements outside of the parent element. See my answer below, it fixed your current issue.

Comment: Is fixed positioning required? Here it's working with absolute instead http://jsfiddle.net/8WNLV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green blocks z-index needs to be lower than the red ones. I used this CSS instead of the one you posted:

```
.foo {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.bar {
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.child {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Works fine, as you can see green is now z-index 1, red is z-index 2 and the blue block has absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

The `z-index` property only has effect within the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) of the containing element.

Put another way, given a bunch of block elements within the same parent element, you can control their front to back ordering pretty easily. However, `z-index` can only control the front to back ordering within this parent element and not within the global context.

So, you can move `.blue` backwards and forwards within `.red` all you like. You can also switch `.red` and `.green` around in the z-plane all you like too. However, you can't put `.green` between `.red` and `.blue` because they are in different stacking contexts.

**EDIT**
Stacking context only applies to elements that are in the flow. If you use `position:absolute`, then you can do this. See Rick Calder's answer

Answer (score 2):

Set your positioning to absolute and remove the z-index from the parent div (the red one) entirely.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/udENm/32/

```
.foo {
background: red;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.bar {
background: green;
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
z-index: 2;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.child {
background: blue;
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
top: 40px;
z-index: 5;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

[Z-index is relative in a way to the parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context). Red is already at 2, and blue is only at z-index 5 compared to it's siblings, but not to outside elements like Green.

> Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of the parent stacking context.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kBv7R/

HTML

```
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="child"></div>
         <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.foo {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.bar {
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.child {
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    left: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

​